# Which raster-format stores Missing, Strings, Variable Names, Multiple Bands?

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, format

I am looking for the ideal raster-format.

GeoTiff stores:

- projection/coordinate-system etc
- numerical values
- missing values
- multiple bands

It does not allow for:

- variable-names. It just does "band 1,2,3..." or "channel 1,2,3...")
- string-values, only numeric

Is there a format suitable for all criteria?

Answer (score 4):

I would argue that a GeoTiff (and any of the other image formats depending on your use-case and sensitivity to different compression methods) ***is*** an ideal format for a raster within the limits of the specification of what a raster is, namely a simple grid of values.  Non-numeric data starts to pose problems for data storage that are better solved by other means, namely a data table of some sort - usually referred to as a Look-Up-Table (LUT).

Storing non-numerical data in a grid format would lead to massive data-bloat, so I am not sure why you would want to do it.  For instance, let's say you have a raster representing land-use with values along the lines of "Agriculture", "Housing", "Industrial" and so on.  Using numeric values and a small LUT, you can have a raster with a pixel depth of one byte (assuming you have 256 land-use types - or potentially even less) and a LUT that would be tiny even stored as uncompressed ascii.  Try doing the same with the non-numerica data and you can see straight away that you will need far more than 8-bits per pixel and for no practical gain (even if you did manage to implement a non-uniform cell-size to reduce data-bloat from shorter attribute values)

LUTs are common fare.  They do exactly what you want.  The [ESRI Grid format](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009t0000000w000000) uses a Value Attribute Table (VAT) to store non-numeric data, which appears a bit more integrated than LUT, but then an ESRI Grid is not just one file but loads of them, so I see no advantage as the VAT for an EXRI Grid is really just a slightly automated LUT.

If you don't want to use a LUT, you could store your data as a serialised multidimensional array (for instance, if you are using Python, you could store your data in a [numpy array](http://scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List#head-b7cd6cc96becec63f4c32dc29e13afccfb66cb77) and then [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) it.  You would then need your own method of handling that (you can do it through GDAL/OGR).  If you're going to do this, though, you might as well just use a database... but you still have all the extra data bloating the system.

Also, a numerical grid is ideal for all sorts of "mapematics".  This is something that is very much more difficult when you include the possibility of a grid holding non-numeric data.

Finally, a numeric-only system means you can have automatic data visualisation by using colours, which is impossible with non-numeric data... unless you use a LUT to convert it to a colour!

So, a GeoTiff is excellent at what it does and a format along the lines you suggest would be non-ideal due to data-bloat and difficulty in visual representation.  Learn to love the raster just the way it is :)

**EDIT (many years later)**
Somebody kindly upvoted this post and that set me thinking.  If you are concerned about losing the LUT or having to bother with two files instead of one, the tiff format allows for non-standard meta data to be stored in its header.  You can therefore store your LUT, perhaps in the format of a Python dictionary or some such.  Then you can read the metadata to get the LUT.  Of course, this is only really useful if you are handling the file by code as a GIS won't know to read the metadata automatically.  But... it's an option.  I've done it for other purposes... so I don't see why it couldn't work for a LUT and you have the security of embedding the LUT codes in the file.